# Fatal Pdflatex - no error

Tags: errors, pdftex, miktex

My pdflatex suddenly decided it would fail compiling all files, complaining about the fact that there are `no errors`. Here are the relevant log lines:

```
INFO  pdflatex - starting with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode ".\Contenu théorique.tex"
INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
INFO  pdflatex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
FATAL pdflatex - No error
FATAL pdflatex - Info: 
FATAL pdflatex - Source: libraries\miktex\texandfriends\include\miktex\c4p\C4P.h
FATAL pdflatex - Line: 477
INFO  pdflatex - finishing with exit code 1
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling MiKTeX to no success and updating it to the very latest version... None of it works. I am using the command line, and when I use Texstudio, the compile command simply crashes.

Comment: If your windows was updated lately it could be that some windows security kicks in. Copy your file to some folder outside the standard folders, rename it too e.g. test.tex and then call in a command line opened in this folder `pdflatex test`. If this fails too you will have to create a trace.

Comment: No recent updates, and that doesn't do it...

Comment: Then you will have to get more info with a trace https://docs.miktex.org/faq/troubleshooting.html

Comment: See also https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/41 which refers to the same code line. If you can build a minimal example that demonstrates the issue you could add it to this bug report.